# Filter Twitter timeline by min_retweets

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

Twitter has these useful filters min_retweets: and min_faves.

Is there a way to use them within my timeline?

Answer (score 1):

search string min_retweets:2 OR min_favs:2

And then, choose search filter "people you follow".

Comment: min_retweets:2, need to have a keyword(s) with it. I want to filter my timeline without specifying any keyword.